# laravel: Route::group - How to understand syntax of :: here. Because there is no Static function `group` inside Route class

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel i am not able to understand what `::` means w.r.t the code `Route:group` or `Route:get` etc.

As per my understanding `::` is used to use static methods from a class.

I check the Route class. but there are no such static methods called `group` or `get`. So how to understand.

Of course i need not uderstand that for the starting my app. But to understand the syntax is good always. I am using phpstorm. Generally i can figure out the links of functions and classes. I tried to look for `group` or `get`  it says not declared.

Comment: This is a good question which is not immediately obvious to laravel users at first without looking carefully through the source, but it is a concept which is used throughout the framework, and helps makes things more expressive syntactically [if you're into facades :)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `Route::method()` like that you're using what's called a "facade". The `Route` class is the facade in this context.

If you take a look at `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route` you'll see that it provides a single static method called `getFacadeAccessor`, which returns a string `router`. It's this string that references an instance of the `Illuminate\Routing\Router` class in the IoC container.

During it's setup Laravel creates an instance of this class and stores it with `router` as kind of like a key.

So when you do `Route::get(...)`, under the hood Laravel is using the facade accessor to find an instance of the Router class that's already been created and calls the `get` method on it. It uses dynamic programming to achieve this, have a look at the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade` class for details of what's going on there, in particular the `__callStatic` method which is where it all starts.

So, calling `Route::get()`:

- You're actually calling `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::get`
- No such method exists on that class, or the `Facade` class it extends, so the `__callStatic` method is run.
- The underlying `Facade` class calls `static::getFacadeRoot()` which if you follow the logic, will get you an instance of `Illuminate\Routing\Router`
- Finally, the `__callStatic` method calls `$instance->$method(...$args);` where `$instance` is the instance of the router, and `$method` is `get` and `$args` is what you passed to `Route::get(...);`
- So when you call `Route::get('route', 'Controller@method');` you actually end up calling `get('route', 'Controller@method')` on an instance of `Illuminate\Routing\Router`. Notice, you're not actually calling a static method.

Comment: can you give some easy explanation of facade in general.

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi Why don't you try the Laravel docs? https://laravel.com/docs/master/facades